# Get-Acl does not seem to work on UNC path?

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, acl

I have difficulty getting `Get-Acl` to work on a UNC path to get the share permissions of a directory and all underlying files and directories.

The code I use looks like this:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Permissions.csv"
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags,FileSystemRights"
del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "\\intranet\sites\folder1\folder2\target-folder-as-root"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -Recurse 
#| where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}-recurse

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    $ACLs = Get-Acl $Folder.Fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }
    foreach ($ACL in $ACLs) {
        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," +
                   $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," +
                   $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags + "," +
                   $ACL.FileSystemRights
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }
}
```

Not taking into account the filename size limit issue this might cause, I get the following error:

```
Get-Acl : Method failed with unexpected error code 1.
At C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ntfs_permissions.ps1:12 char:10
+     $ACLs = Get-Acl $Folder.Fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

I find documentation on listing the shared permissions on a shared drive using the UNC path (I don't want to list the permissions starting from the root, but only starting from a subfolder) is very limited.

Comment: Get-ACL will show the file system permissions for a standard SMB share path, however I get the same error when attempting to use Get-ACL with a SharePoint site as it appears you are attempting to do. I believe that may be because it is actually using WebDav and not SMB.

Comment: Can you guide me further on how to get the shared permissions of my sharefile?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have much SharePoint administration experience. I suggest you do some research on the available SharePoint PowerShell snap-ins or modules to see if they have a cmdlet that will allow you to get permissions on a document library.

Comment: Any ideas here, Mapping an UNC path to a network drive does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `$ACLs = (Get-Acl $Folder.fullname).Access`

Instead of: `$ACLs = Get-Acl $Folder.Fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }`